# Permutations of a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h', 'r', 'w']]
```

I want to pick an element from each list and combine them to be a string.

For example: 'aag', 'aah', 'aar', 'aaw', 'abg', 'abh' ....

However, the length of the list l and the length of each inner list are all unknown before the program is running. So how can I do want I want?

Comment: Do you want all combinations, or a random one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535924/simple-way-to-create-possible-case/2535934#2535934) and use `itertools.product(*l)` instead.

Comment: To spell it out: `[''.join(s) for s in itertools.product(*l)]`

Comment: @wong2 you mean fantastic I hope? Fantasy is quite a bit different :)

Comment: can you explain the * operator?  i feel like i never 100% got it

Comment: @jon_darkstar: It unpacks a sequence into positional arguments.

Comment: @Jon: the `*` operator substitutes the elements of a sequence as arguments in a call; if `l == [1, 2, 3]` then `f(*l)` is the same as `f(1, 2, 3)`; accordingly, `astring.replace(*"ab")` is a dumb way of calling `astring.replace("a", "b")`.

Answer (score 7):

If anybody's interested in the algorithm, here's a very simple way to use recursion to find the combos:

```
 l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h', 'r', 'w']]
 def permu(lists, prefix=''):
      if not lists:
           print prefix
           return
      first = lists[0]
      rest = lists[1:]
      for letter in first:
           permu(rest, prefix + letter)
 permu(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

using recursion

```
def permutenew(l):
if len(l)==1:
    return l[0]
else:   
    lnew=[]
    for a in l[0]:
        for b in permutenew(l[1:]):
            lnew.append(a+b)
    return lnew

l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h', 'r', 'w']]
print permutenew(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Piggy-backing off of [JasonWoof's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233871/1762224). The following will create a list instead of printing. Be mindful that this may be very slow as it requires a lot of memory to store the values.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools # Not actually used in the code below

def permu(lists):
    def fn(lists, group=[], result=[]):
        if not lists:
            result.append(group)
            return
        first, rest = lists[0], lists[1:]
        for letter in first:
            fn(rest, group + [letter], result)
    result = []
    fn(lists, result=result)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ll = [ [[1, 2, 3], [5, 10], [42]],
           [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h', 'r', 'w']] ]
    nth = lambda i: 'Permutation #{0}:\n{1}'.format(i, '-'*16)

    # Note: permu(list) can be replaced with itertools.product(*l)
    [[print(p) for p in [nth(i)]+permu(l)+['\n']] for i,l in enumerate(ll)]
```

Result

```
Permutation #0:
----------------
[1, 5, 42]
[1, 10, 42]
[2, 5, 42]
[2, 10, 42]
[3, 5, 42]
[3, 10, 42]


Permutation #1:
----------------
['a', 'a', 'g']
['a', 'a', 'h']
['a', 'a', 'r']
['a', 'a', 'w']
['a', 'b', 'g']
['a', 'b', 'h']
['a', 'b', 'r']
['a', 'b', 'w']
['b', 'a', 'g']
['b', 'a', 'h']
['b', 'a', 'r']
['b', 'a', 'w']
['b', 'b', 'g']
['b', 'b', 'h']
['b', 'b', 'r']
['b', 'b', 'w']
['c', 'a', 'g']
['c', 'a', 'h']
['c', 'a', 'r']
['c', 'a', 'w']
['c', 'b', 'g']
['c', 'b', 'h']
['c', 'b', 'r']
['c', 'b', 'w']
```

---

Below is an equivalent substitution for [`itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> This function is equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory:

```py
def product(*args, **kwds):
    pools = list(map(tuple, args)) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy with itertools.product :

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product("abc", "ab", "ghrw"))
[('a', 'a', 'g'), ('a', 'a', 'h'), ('a', 'a', 'r'), ('a', 'a', 'w'), ('a', 'b', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'h'), ('a', 'b', 'r'), ('a', 'b', 'w'), ('b', 'a', 'g'), ('b', 'a', 'h'), ('b', 'a', 'r'), ('b', 'a', 'w'), ('b', 'b', 'g'), ('b', 'b', 'h'), ('b', 'b', 'r'), ('b', 'b', 'w'), ('c', 'a', 'g'), ('c', 'a', 'h'), ('c', 'a', 'r'), ('c', 'a', 'w'), ('c', 'b', 'g'), ('c', 'b', 'h'), ('c', 'b', 'r'), ('c', 'b', 'w')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
reduce(lambda a,b: [i+j for i in a for j in b], l)

OUT: ['aag', 'aah', 'aar', 'aaw', 'abg', 'abh', 'abr', 'abw', 'bag', 'bah', 'bar', 'baw', 'bbg', 'bbh', 'bbr', 'bbw', 'cag', 'cah', 'car', 'caw', 'cbg', 'cbh', 'cbr', 'cbw']
```

If you'd like to reuse/regeneralize:

```
def opOnCombos(a,b, op=operator.add):
    return [op(i,j) for i in a for j in b]

def f(x):
    return lambda a,b: opOnCombo(a,b,x)

reduce(opOnCombos, l) //same as before
reduce(f(operator.mul), l))  //multiply combos of several integer list
```