# How to print each possible permutation of several arrays of strings on Python?

Tags: python, arrays, permutation, set-theory

Let's say I have the following arrays of strings:

```
Background = {"Ocean"}
Body = {"Normal"}
Eyes = {"Big", "Small", "Monolid"}
Color = {"Yellow", "White", "Red Rose", "Turquoise", "Dark green", "Orange"}
Hands = {"None", "Robot", "Spider", "Bear"}
Extra = {"Empty", "Sand", "Dust", "Graffiti", "Aloe"}
```

I want to print a list that contains all possible permutations of each element mentioned in the arrays above, following the order in which these arrays were set (i.e. it starts checking on `Background`, then goes to check `Body`, then `Eyes`, then `Color`, then `Hands`, and finishes on `Extra`).

The first permutation should be:

```
1. Ocean, Normal, Big, Yellow, None, Empty
```

The second permutation should be:

```
2. Ocean, Normal, Big, Yellow, None, Sand
```

And so on...

It can be assumed that the item `None` is the same as `Empty`.

How could I do that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535934/8739330

Comment: @West This solution also works I think, but I don't know where in that line of code can I set a counter ```i```, also, do you know if there's a formula I could use to check if the final number of ```i``` is really the total number of permutations for this case?

Comment: Seen your comment on accepted answer. `i` in that case will definitely be the total number of permutations. For my suggested solution, you can just get the length of the resulting list and compare that to your final `i`  in accepted answer. If they are the same, you can then just use the fastest option.

Comment: @West Thank you. Also, I just realized that by multiplying each number of elements in each array, you ended up with the total number of permutations, i.e. 1x1x3x6x4x5 = 360

Comment: Oh nice, I never thought of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution should work
Assume arrays are as follows

```
Backgrounds = ["Ocean"]
Bodys = ["Normal"]
Eyes = ["Big", "Small", "Monolid"]
Colors = ["Yellow", "White", "Red Rose", "Turquoise", "Dark green", "Orange"]
Hands = ["None", "Robot", "Spider", "Bear"]
Extra = ["Empty", "Sand", "Dust", "Graffiti", "Aloe"]
for background in Backgrounds:
    for body in Bodys:
       for eye in Eyes:
           for colour in colours:
                 for hand in Hands:
                      for extra in extras:
                             print(background,body,eye,colour,hand,extra)
```

If your lists are really large please don't use the above solution because its time complexity is o(n^6).

Comment: Cool, I think it works, I also added ```i = 0``` right before the first for loop and ```i +=1``` right before ```print(i,background,body,eye,colour,hand,extra)```, the counter goes up to 360, is there a formula I can use to evaluate if this total number of permutations (i.e. 360) is actually the right one for this case?

Comment: i+=1 should be after the print statement.  If you wish only the first 360 outputs please add a break statement inside for loop. if you want 360th output no need for forloops.  Also, accept answer if it works